# How to convert ViewResult.Model to a Model Object in asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to convert my result.Model into Post model in my test method. But i am getting null.

My Controller Action Method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> EditPost(int id)
    {
        var post = await _blogService.QueryPosts()
                    .Include(x => x.PostCategories)
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);

        var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(x =>
            x.CreateMap<Post, SavePostViewModel>());

        var mapper = mapperConfig.CreateMapper();

        var model = mapper.Map<Post, SavePostViewModel>(post);

        model.CategoryIds = post.PostCategories.Select(x => x.CategoryId).ToList();

        return View(model);
    }
```

My Test Method:

```
[Test]
[TestCase(1, 2)]
[TestCase(2, 3)]
public async Task HttpGet_EditPost_When_Id_Is_Valid_Get_Correct_Post(int postId, int 
expectedTotalPostCategories)
  {
        // Act 
        var result = await _blogController.EditPost(postId) as ViewResult;
        var post = result.Model as Post;

        // Assert
        Assert.IsInstanceOf<ViewResult>(result);
        Assert.IsNotNull(post);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedTotalPostCategories, post.PostCategories.Count);
    }
```

Comment: check if `post` is `null`, because it's a result of `FirstOrDefault`, if not, post the definitions of `Post` and `SavePostViewModel`

Comment: @tchelidze thanks a lot. It's work me.